# How to say THANK YOU for all the awesome answers here?

Tags: discussion

I'm an Android developer and I'm using this site for like 2 years, it literally saves me **EVERY single day**, and the only  thing i wish I could do is to say THANK YOU to all the people who post all the awesome and elegant answers here. Now since i have no reputation or privileges or whatever I can't do that. So I maybe there could be something as simple as the LIKE button for all those answers, just the like, no vote up no nothing, it can even be private and only visible to the person who answered, or I dont know, I just wanna say **![THANK YOU][1]**, that's it

Comment: You could express your thanks by answering some of the questions.

Comment: Alex beat me to it. Take the expertise you are developing and help others. *Pass it on.*

Comment: And, if you gained some reputation, help moderating by flagging and voting...

Comment: Spend some time helping other users and housekeeping the site.